# Score board moves with Character movement in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a C# script which is for a game in unity. When I run the scene, the Player/ character moves with the score board (want the score board not to move, for obvious reasons). I had a issue with Nullref error before, but fixed that and now the score board is an issue. **All objects were imported/ created in the Assets folder and dragged to the world scene/ main scene.**

Here's the code:

```
public class Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioClip collectCoins;
    public AudioSource audioSource;

    public Text _mytext;

    int i = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("coin"))


        {
            i += 10;
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(collectCoins);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            
        }

        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("coin2"))

        {
            i -= 10;
            if (i < 0)
            {
                i = 0;
            }
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(collectCoins);
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            
        }
    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
    }
    float speed =0.2f;

    void Update()
    {
        if(_mytext != null)
            {
                _mytext.text = "Bonus: " + i;
            }
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
       
        transform.Translate(move, 0, 0);
        

        

    }


}
```

Its the strangest thing...Tried everything...any ideas to what I should do? (appreciate any replies).

Comment: Is this scoreboard added as a child inside player/ character?. Is the score board used as HUD or in world space?.I think the script has nothing to do with scoreboard moving.Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'll edit the question above...

Comment: Where is this text added in hierarchy window?Is it added as child inside the player transform?

Comment: Its inside Canvas, which is a child of Samplescene

Comment: ok . So if you click the canvas then on the inspector the render mode will be Screen Space-Overlay. If that is selected the text/score will be shown in the screen like in most games the score will shown at top.

Comment: Played around with Inspector. The text/ score still moves with the character

Comment: Is the score shown on the screen? or is it added in world space?

Comment: have it on screen space - camera (main camera)...its still moving. Has the solution got to do with "order in layer"?

Comment: you can update question with images also.That will help other contributors

Comment: The structure here is killing me. I can't help you because I can't determine your intent here. Your script is called `Script` which doesn't tell me *at all* what it's supposed to do - is this for the player or for the scoreboard? I can't tell by looking into the script, either - why would a player script have a `Text` or `AudioClip`? Why would a scoreboard have a `speed` or `move`? Class names and variable names are all great ways to give *context* and explain to others what you're doing. `Script` and `_myText` don't give any hints as to what you'll use them for.

Comment: Sorry about the naming scheme. 

I realised I attached the Script class to the Text object and not Canvas (and put public int i=0 at start of script)...everything works as it should now!!!